# Convert Two Col layout for Mobile

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to make this layout responsive for mobile and nothing seems to make it work. I am trying to stack these two columns on a mobile layout.

you can see the current layout in its entirety here.
https://goodclickmedia.com/2-col-layout/

I only included the top two columns to reduce code on the post.

Specifically, I need a media break on this page at the mobile device level say 600px. So that when this page is accessed via mobile, the tiles will stack on top of each other and produce a single column. I've tried a number of @media tweaks and nothing seems to impact .container

```css
<style>

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
}


.container {  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 10px 10px;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-areas:
      "Col-One Col-Two"
      "Col-Three Col-Four"
      "Col-Five Col-Six"
      "Col-Seven Col-Eight"
      "Col-Nine Col-Ten";
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .Col-One {  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1.5fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-areas:
      "Left-Nest-Lt-Col Left-Nest-Rt-Col";
    grid-area: Col-One;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #cacaca;
    max-width: 550px;
  }
  
  .Left-Nest-Rt-Col { grid-area: Left-Nest-Rt-Col; }
  
  .Left-Nest-Lt-Col { 
    grid-area: Left-Nest-Lt-Col; 
    max-width: 125px; 
    border: 1px green !important; 
}
  
  .Col-Two {  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1.5fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-areas:
      "Rt-Nest-Lt-Col2 Rt-Nest-Rt-Col2";
    grid-area: Col-Two;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #cacaca;
    max-width: 550px;
  }
  
  .Rt-Nest-Lt-Col2 { grid-area: Rt-Nest-Lt-Col2; }
  
  .Rt-Nest-Rt-Col2 { grid-area: Rt-Nest-Rt-Col2; }
  
  
  /* ZOOM IN FEATURE - RAISED SECTION ELEMENT - COMMENT ADDED BY JOHN CHAMBERS */
.zoom {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
  width: 550px;
  height: 125px;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
}

.block:hover {
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

.block:hover, .block:hover h2 {
    color:#DC582A ;
}

.block:hover, .block:hover p {
    color:#202020 ;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6,
.heading {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #202020;
  font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="Col-One zoom block">
      <div class="Left-Nest-Lt-Col"><img style="padding-top:5px; height: 125px;" border="0" src="https://staging9.flashglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/icon_list_400px_2.png"></div>
      <div class="Left-Nest-Rt-Col"><h2>TITLE HERE</h2><p>Some copy goes here that will be reflective of title.</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Col-Two zoom block">
      <div class="Rt-Nest-Lt-Col2"><img style="padding-top:5px; height: 125px;" border="0" src="https://staging9.flashglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/icon_list_400px_2.png"></div>
      <div class="Rt-Nest-Rt-Col2"><h2>TITLE HERE2</h2><p>Some copy goes here that will be reflective of title.</p></div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
```

Comment: I hope the code not being included was why I got the two negative clicks

Comment: Firstly, thanks for including your current code in the form of a snippet. However, I feel like it would help if you described a **specific behavior** you want to have happen. Simply saying you want the page/UI elements to be "responsive" is somewhat broad, and is likely not going to lead to a specific answer to your problem (i.e. it could lead to an answer that is not beneficial to you). For example, you could include a specific size that the page needs to be for the two columns to stack on top of each other.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the requirement is for the two children of `div.container` to stack vertically when the screen width is < 600px? If so, you should [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification - I do try to solve these things on my own - honestly I do! 

Specifically, I need a media break on this page at the mobile device level say 600px. So that when this page is accessed via mobile, the tiles will stack on top of each other and produce a single column. I've tried a number of @media tweaks and nothing seems to impact .container

Comment: As I said, that information should be in the question, not comments. I've voted to reopen, assuming you'll do so.

Comment: Thank you for the direct communication. I've updated the initial question with those specifics.

Comment: @JohnNobody if one of the answers addresses your question, please upvote it and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things:

1. `min-width` is exactly that, the minimum width when the styles/properties will start to affect elements. What you want, in this example, is `max-width`
2. CSS, including `media queries` is cascading, so a `max-width` media query will need to come AFTER all your other styles.
3. **EDIT** Mobile first below. Original: (And we won't get into this), you should start (in my opinion) with the mobile styles and then change with `min-width` media queries, since often times only a few properties on selectors will change as the browser window increases in width.

What I changed - keeping the CSS Grid styles. (you can certainly change the `.container` to a flex parent.)

1. Added a `max-width` media query after everything.
2. Reset the grid-area styles

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: initial;
  }
  .block {
    grid-area: initial;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "Col-One Col-Two" "Col-Three Col-Four" "Col-Five Col-Six" "Col-Seven Col-Eight" "Col-Nine Col-Ten";
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.Col-One {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1.5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "Left-Nest-Lt-Col Left-Nest-Rt-Col";
  grid-area: Col-One;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #cacaca;
  max-width: 550px;
}

.Left-Nest-Rt-Col {
  grid-area: Left-Nest-Rt-Col;
}

.Left-Nest-Lt-Col {
  grid-area: Left-Nest-Lt-Col;
  max-width: 125px;
  border: 1px green !important;
}

.Col-Two {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1.5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "Rt-Nest-Lt-Col2 Rt-Nest-Rt-Col2";
  grid-area: Col-Two;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #cacaca;
  max-width: 550px;
}

.Rt-Nest-Lt-Col2 {
  grid-area: Rt-Nest-Lt-Col2;
}

.Rt-Nest-Rt-Col2 {
  grid-area: Rt-Nest-Rt-Col2;
}


/* ZOOM IN FEATURE - RAISED SECTION ELEMENT - COMMENT ADDED BY JOHN CHAMBERS */

.zoom {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  transition: transform .2s;
  /* Animation */
  width: 550px;
  height: 125px;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
}

.block:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.block:hover,
.block:hover h2 {
  color: #DC582A;
}

.block:hover,
.block:hover p {
  color: #202020;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6,
.heading {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #202020;
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: initial;
  }
  .block {
    grid-area: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Col-One zoom block">
    <div class="Left-Nest-Lt-Col"><img style="padding-top:5px; height: 125px;" border="0" src="https://staging9.flashglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/icon_list_400px_2.png"></div>
    <div class="Left-Nest-Rt-Col">
      <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
      <p>Some copy goes here that will be reflective of title.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Col-Two zoom block">
    <div class="Rt-Nest-Lt-Col2"><img style="padding-top:5px; height: 125px;" border="0" src="https://staging9.flashglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/icon_list_400px_2.png"></div>
    <div class="Rt-Nest-Rt-Col2">
      <h2>TITLE HERE2</h2>
      <p>Some copy goes here that will be reflective of title.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

#### Opinionated Mobile First

Here's mobile first and after looking at your site, this can be super simplified:

1. A display property doesn't necessarily need to be set until `601px` and higher, your `blocks` will stack because they are block elements.
2. The media query for the `grid` is below the rest of the CSS.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1.5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #cacaca;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.l-col {
  max-width: 125px;
  border: 1px green !important;
}


/* ZOOM IN FEATURE - RAISED SECTION ELEMENT - COMMENT ADDED BY JOHN CHAMBERS */

.zoom {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  transition: transform .2s;
  /* Animation */
  width: 550px;
  height: 125px;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
}

.block:hover {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.block:hover,
.block:hover h2 {
  color: #DC582A;
}

.block:hover,
.block:hover p {
  color: #202020;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6,
.heading {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #202020;
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media (min-width:601px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr); /* the 10 can change to however many rows you actually need */
    gap: 10px 10px;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
  }
  .block {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="zoom block">
    <div class="l-col"><img style="padding-top:5px; height: 125px;" border="0" src="https://staging9.flashglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/icon_list_400px_2.png"></div>
    <div class="r-col">
      <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
      <p>Some copy goes here that will be reflective of title.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="zoom block">
    <div class="l-col"><img style="padding-top:5px; height: 125px;" border="0" src="https://staging9.flashglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/icon_list_400px_2.png"></div>
    <div class="r-col">
      <h2>TITLE HERE2</h2>
      <p>Some copy goes here that will be reflective of title.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is incredibly insightful. Thank you so much! I will look into this further and see if I can't make it work on my end with the full version. You've been tremendously helpful. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @JohnNobody glad I could help. Good luck. Hopefully both snippets help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your media query to this

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

your current query says `min-width: 600px;` so anything that meets that requirement and has a minimum width of 600px will accept the styles inside. by writing `max-width: 600px` anthing under 600px will accept the styles inside. To get the elements to stack I used `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: Thank you for your response. When i dropped this in, it stacked everything at the normal width. I only wish for it to stack at the under 600. So you're saying that I need to set a min-width on each class to ensure it behaves correctly?

Comment: No, with the media queries the idea is that this code will overwrite the code that is outside of a media query. In this case you have it set to `display: grid;` and the media query is re-writing the `display` property to be `display:flex;`